# Zeroes of rational functions

Tags: rational-functions

I am reading upon the rational functions and came across this question. 
How to prove that a rational function F(s) cannot be zero on any interval on the $j\omega$ axis? 
 
By intuition, we can say that a rational function can have only a finite number of zeros.But how to prove this.

Comment: "The $\;j\omega\;$ axis"? What is that?

Comment: By saying $j\omega$ axis, I mean the imaginary axis in the complex plane.

Comment: But then the above is true *not only* for rational function but for any meromorphic non-zero function: it cannot vanish on any interval of positive length on any axis or whatever.

Comment: @DonAntonio can you please provide a proof for "Any meromorphic non-zero function cannot vanish on any interval".